# prove $f(x)=x^2$ for any $x \in I$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> A function $f$ is continuous on an interval $I$ and for each rational number $r \in I$, it is true that $f(r)=r^2$. Prove $f(x)=x^2$ for any $x \in I$

my take:

$x^2$ is continuous at every point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ because it's polynomial. 
$$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to x_o} f(x) = \displaystyle\lim_{x \to x_o} x^2 = (\displaystyle\lim_{x \to x_o} x) (\displaystyle\lim_{x \to x_o} x) \text {by limit laws, since each limit exists}$$

$$= x_0 * x_0$$

$$f = x^2 \text{ is continuous at each}, x_o \in \mathbb{R}$$

Above, is my take for the question, but a friend of mine told me that we have to use sequence s.t $g: I \to \mathbb{R}, g(x) = f(x)-x^2$.. but i don't know how to use this method.

Is my method correct? and if not, how do i use my friends method?

Comment: This doesn't work if we take the interval $[x,x]$ with $x$ irrational.

Comment: Why would it not work? There is still a sequence of rationals approaching $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function is continuous iff for every sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $x_n \to x$, it follows that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. This should be enough for you to prove your result, given that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and thus in any interval.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose not, then there is $x_0\in I$ with $|f(x_0)-x_0^2|>0$. Notice the function $g(x)=|f(x)-x^2|$ is continuous, so there is $\delta$ so that if $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $g(x)>0$. This is a contradiction, since there are rational numbers arbitrarily close to $x_0$, and for any rational number $z\in I$ we have $g(z)=0$.